# Get all entries within working hours excluding weekends

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to make two queries into Useractivities, one where i find all entries within working hours (mon-fri 08-16) and one where I find all entries outside of this timespan.

```
Useractivity.where('activity = ? AND created_at >= ? AND EXTRACT (HOUR from created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ?', 'login',Time.now.since(-7.days).to_date, 8,16).count

Useractivity.where('activity = ? AND created_at >= ? AND EXTRACT (HOUR from created_at) NOT BETWEEN ? AND ?', 'login',Time.now.since(-7.days).to_date, 8,16).count
```

How can i exclude saturdays and sundays for the first query, and include them (for all hours) in the second query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add an extra condition in the WHERE clause.

For the working days it is:

```
... AND EXTRACT(dow FROM created_at) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 ...
```

And for weekend days:

```
... AND EXTRACT(dow FROM created_at) NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 5 ...
```